# Scope, operators, function errors help needed

Tags: c++, scope, operators

I have some questions about this program. Ill explain what it does quick first. It reads in names and statistics from a file that looks like this:

```
1880 John 0.081541 boy
1880 William 0.080511 boy
1880 James 0.050057 boy
1880 Charles 0.045167 boy
1904 Zola 0.000157 girl
1904 Juana 0.000154 girl
1904 Ramona 0.000154 girl
1904 Carmella 0.00015 girl
```

I am to read it and store in a dynamic array and be able to organize with methods. My questions are:
1) What is wrong with my extraction operators? Why can't it see the people array? Should I open the file there?
2) Why can't my main see the checkLines function? I don't think it should be a member function, I think it should be stand alone.
3)What is wrong with my copy constructor? There is a yellow line and not a red one and the error is the following:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Member 'capacity' was not initialized in this 
     constructor
    - Member 'people' was not initialized in this 
     constructor
    - Member 'fillCount' was not initialized in this 
     constructor
```

Here is the code

BabyNames.h

```
#ifndef BABYNAMES_H_
#define BABYNAMES_H_
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


/**
 * gender: an enum to hold types boy and girl
 */
enum gender {boy, girl};

/**
 * PeopleStats: a data struct to hold year, name, double, and the enum type
 * gender
 */
struct PeopleStats {
    short year;
    string name;
    double percent;
    gender sex;
};

/**
 * Names: A class that reads data from a file into a PeopleStats Array
 * and is capable of sorting them by name and by popularity percentage
 */
class BabyNames {

public:
    int checklines(const char fn[]);
    BabyNames(BabyNames& people);
    BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines);
    ~BabyNames();
    gender parseSex(string s);
    void swap(int i);
    const int getCapacity();//getter for dataSize
    const PeopleStats& get(int i) const; //getter for objects of the data array
    void sortByName();      //Sorts the names alphabetically
    void sortByPopularity();//Sorts the names by popularity
    void sortByYear();
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PeopleStats& d);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const BabyNames& bn);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, PeopleStats& ac);
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, BabyNames& ac);
     //int filled; //keeps track of how many array locations have data objects

private:
    static const int MAX_DATA_SIZE = 2000;
    PeopleStats* people;


    int capacity;
    int fillCount; // to keep track of how many array locations have data objects in them
    static const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS = -1;

};//end of class


#endif  /* BABYNAMES_H */
```

BabyNames.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include "BabyNames.h"




/**
 * BabyNames: A class that reads data from a file into a PeopleStats Array
 * and is capable of sorting them by name and by popularity percentage
 */


BabyNames::BabyNames(const char fn[], const int numLines) {
    people = new PeopleStats[numLines];
    capacity = numLines;    //set current capacity
    ifstream myfile;        //Open File
    myfile.open(fn);        //read in data
    int filled = 0;
    while (filled < capacity) {
        myfile >> people[filled].year;
        myfile >> people[filled].name;
        myfile >> people[filled].percent;
        string sex;
        myfile >> sex;
        people[filled].sex = parseSex(sex);
        filled++;
    }

}

//Copy Constructor
BabyNames::BabyNames(BabyNames& people){
    PeopleStats* copyPeople = new PeopleStats[];
    for (int i=0; i<500 ;i++)
        copyPeople[i] = people[i];
}

PeopleStats& operator =(const PeopleStats& people){
    PeopleStats x = new PeopleStats[2000];
    for (int i=0; i<2000 ;i++)
        x[i] = people[i];
    return *this;
}//make a member with one parameter


std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, PeopleStats& ac){
string str;
ifstream myfile;        //Open File
    myfile.open(fn);        //read in data
    int filled = 0;
myfile >> people[filled].year;
        myfile >> people[filled].name;
        myfile >> people[filled].percent;
        string sex;
        myfile >> sex;
        people[filled].sex = parseSex(sex);
        filled++;
        }
    }//struct doesnt need a loop in the operator
    return in;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, BabyNames& ac){
string str;

    while (in >> str){
        string strInput;
        getline(inf, strInput);
        in >> strInput;

    }//struct doesnt need a loop in the operator
    return in;
}
//Baby names extraction operator does need a loop

int checkLines(const char fn[]){
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    ifstream myfile("textexample.txt");
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        ++number_of_lines;
    std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
    return number_of_lines;
}//make a stand alone function



BabyNames::~BabyNames(){
    cout << "Destructor to deallocate memory... Done!" << endl;
    delete[]people;
}


/*
 * sortByName - Sorts the entire array of people by name using the bubble
 * sort algorithm. Array is sorted according to name, within the structure
 * Algorithm becomes extremely slow if capacity > 3000
 */
void BabyNames::sortByName(){
    //sorted is set to true if no changes were made
    bool sorted = false;
    //change tells the loop if we made a swap or not
    bool change = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
            int compare = people[i].name.compare(people[i + 1].name);
            if (compare == 1) {
                swap(i);
                change = true;
            }
        }
        //if the array was not changed,
        //changed sorted to true and exit loop
        if (change == false)
            sorted = true;
        //otherwise reset change and repeat the loop
        else
            change = false;
    }
}

/**
 * sortByPopularity - sorts the entire array using the bubble sort algorithm
 * Method is almost exactly the same as sortByName, except the compare
 * variable is a double consisting of the difference of the two popularity
 * percentages.
 * Algorithm becomes extremely slow if capacity > 3000
 */
void BabyNames::sortByPopularity(){
    bool sorted = false;
    bool change = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
            double compare = people[i].percent - people[i + 1].percent;
            if (compare < 0) {
                swap(i);
                change = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (change == false)
            sorted = true;
        change = false;
    }
}

void BabyNames::sortByYear(){
    bool sorted = false;
    bool change = false;
    while (!sorted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity - 1; i++) {
            double compare = people[i].year - people[i + 1].year;
            if (compare < 0) {
                swap(i);
                change = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (change == false)
            sorted = true;
        change = false;
    }
}
/**
 * swap - swaps the positions of people[i] and people[i + 1]
 * @param i - index of the people array that will get swapped with i + 1
 */
void BabyNames::swap(int i) {
    PeopleStats temp = people[i + 1];
    people[i + 1] = people[i];
    people[i] = temp;
}
/**     string strInput;
        getline(inf, strInput);
        in >> strInput;
 * parseSex: extracts the gender from the input and returns the appropriate enum
 * @param s
 * @return gender object
 */
gender BabyNames::parseSex(string s) {
    if (s == "boy")
        return boy;
    else if (s == "girl")
        return girl;
    else
        throw "invalid Gender";
}

/**
 * getCapacity: returns the number of data entries stored.
 * @return size of the data
 */
const int BabyNames::getCapacity(){
    return capacity;
}
/**
 * get: returns one PeopleStat Object
 * @param i
 * @require: i < capacity
 * @return PeopleStat object
 */
const PeopleStats& BabyNames::get(int i) const {
    if (i>=0 && i < capacity)
        return people[i];
    throw OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
}
/**
 * << - overloads the outstream operator for PeopleStats object
 * @param os
 * @param d
 * @return os : output stream
 */
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream& os, const PeopleStats& d){
    os << d.name << " " << d.year << " " << d.percent << " " << d.sex;
    return os;
}

/**
 * <<: overloads the outstream operator for the BabyNames object
 * @param os
 * @param bn
 * @return
 */
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const BabyNames& bn) {
    os << "  BabyNames object " << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 2000; i++ )
        os << "    " << (i+1) <<":  " << bn.get( i ) << std::endl;
    return os;
}//end of operator
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BabyNames.h"




/**
 * main: The client function that controls the server, BabyNames
 * For reasons currently unknown, the program will take forever
 * to run after the  * 3000-5000 line mark.
 * @return 0 if successful
 */
int main(void) {
/*    cout << "People names: " << endl;
    BabyNames names("src/people.txt", 2000);
    cout << names;

    cout << "Sorted by popularity" << endl;
    names.sortByPopularity();
    cout << names;
//    cout << "Sorted by name" << endl;
//    names.sortByName();
//    cout << names;
        cout << "Sorted by year" << endl;
        names.sortByYear();
        cout << names;
    cout << "... done!" << endl;
    return 0;*/

    cout << "Baby names: " << endl;

    const char filename[] = "src/people.txt";
    cout << " 1. Reading file: \"" << filename << "\" ... ";
    int number_of_names = checkLines(filename);
    cout << " number of lines in file is: " << "2000";
    BabyNames* names = new BabyNames( "src/people.txt", 2000 );

    // read the contents of a file into names and print them
    ifstream file( filename, ios::in );
    file >> *names;
    cout << " file has been read!" << endl;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 2. Sorted by popularity:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByPop = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByPop->sortByPopularity();
    cout << *namesByPop;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 3. Sorted by name:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByName = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByName->sortByName();
    cout << *namesByName;

    // Sort and print
    cout << " 4. Sorted by year:" << endl;
    BabyNames* namesByYear = new BabyNames( *names );
    namesByYear->sortByYear();
    cout << *namesByYear;

    cout << " 5. Original names:" << endl;
    cout << *names;

    delete names;
    delete namesByYear;
    delete namesByName;
    delete namesByPop;



    cout << "... all done!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Because your extraction operator is not a member of the class. You need `ac.people`. You should defintely not open a file in your extraction operator, the opened file (or whatever) is passed in through the `in` parameter.

2) Because you haven't told main about it (i.e. you haven't defined it anywhere that main can see). Perhaps simplest would be to add `int checkLines(const char fn[]);` near the bottom of BabyNames.h.

3) Everything is wrong with your copy constructor. For one thing it doesn't initialise the object you are constructing, instead it just creates an array called copyPeople which then gets discarded, the object you are constructing is completely untouched. Another issue is that the parameter should be declared `const`. Something like this would be better

```
//Copy Constructor
BabyNames::BabyNames(const BabyNames& bn){
    people = new PeopleStats[bn.capacity];
    for (int i=0; i<bn.capacity ;i++)
        people[i] = bn.people[i];
    capacity = bn.capacity;
    fillCount = bn.fillCount;
}
```

Your assignment operator is wrong too, for similar reasons.